# "ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout ORA-29400: data cartridge error" When Trying to Run Select Stmt on External Table

Tags: linux, oracle

My database has an external table (my_ext_table) that points to a text file (my_text_file.txt) on the database server hard drive. When I connect to the database server with TOAD I use my database username and password (my_db_account). To access the text file, I use a completely different user (my_linux_os_account) that accesses the database server using terminal services.

When I try to select data from my_ext_table from TOAD, I get the following error:

```
[Error] Execution (25: 30): 
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04005: error while accessing file /my_server_dir/my_text_file.txt
```

The log file has the following errors in it:

```
KUP-04017: OS message: Permission denied
KUP-04118: operation "open failed", location "SlfOpen1"
```

I am able to query the table when logged into terminal services as my_linux_os_account and I use sqlplus logging in as my_db_account.

I would like to be able to query the table using TOAD.

My co-worker suggested I should try to proxy as the my_linux_os_account user.

Is it possible to do that from the TOAD Editor window? What tool should I be using to proxy as a different user to access the data with a select statement?

Alternatively, is it possible to alter the perms on the text file so that my database user has rights to the text file?

Comment: If I remember correctly, that error message is kind of generic and could mean a lot of different problems.  Check the file's directory for a .bad file, it may list some rows that are formatted incorrectly or provide other helpful information.

Comment: @JonHeller There are thousands of rows in the .bad file, so I tried to do this with a simple Hello World type of test. No bad file was created, but a log file was. I put the log file errors in the question. Message says permission denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the query to work from TOAD I modified the permissions on my_text_file.txt:

```
chmod o=r my_text_file.txt
```